# Android apps - are users automatically notified of new versions

Tags: android

Are there any special requirements my app should obey to ensure users are notofied when an update is available? (My current app is freeware if it matters)

Comment: Google plays pushes a notification to all the users connected via internet stating that there is an update for your app. So you just have to upload your apk and watch the show.

Comment: @AndroSelva Thanks for the information. I was unsure if there could be situations where I had to do more, but nice to have it confirmed that it will work out of the box :)

Answer (score 1):

Google play shows automatic update once you release a newer version of your app in google play. But the update can be see only if the user visits your app in Google play.

If you want to show the update notification at the launch of your application, then some extra coding is required.

You can write a code inside the start of your application to read a file from some server, which contains the version number of your app. 
Evereytime you update the application, you can change the version number in the server.

So, once the app gets a different version number as compared t previous one saved in sharedPreference, you can write logic to launch googleplay to update your app and also update your sharedPreference with latest version number.

Hope you understand what I am trying to say.